# UPDATE of SQLITE3 PDO PHP does not work while there is a match

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I've created a SQLite3 database through PHP and PDO
Insert record and Delete record works fine but UPDATE record does not

```
public function update_All($mStore_Order_DataClass) {
            try 
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE Orders "
                        . "SET x_Name = :x_Name, "
                        . "x_PhoneNumber1 = :x_PhoneNumber1, "
                        . "x_PhoneNumber2 = :x_PhoneNumber2, "
                        . "x_Address1 = :x_Address1, "
                        . "x_Date = :x_Date, "
                        . "x_Time = :x_Time, "
                        . "x_Status = :x_Status, "
                        . "x_M2 = :x_M2, "
                        . "x_M3 = :x_M3, "
                        . "x_Barcode = :Barcode, "
                        . "x_Price = :x_Price, "
                        . "x_Discount = :x_Discount, "
                        . "x_Number = :x_Number "
                        . "WHERE x_ID = :x_ID ";

                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

                $stmt->bindValue(':x_ID'          , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_ID()          );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Name'        , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Name()        );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_PhoneNumber1', $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_PhoneNumber1());
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_PhoneNumber2', $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_PhoneNumber2());
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Address1'    , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Address1()    );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Date'        , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Date()        );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Time'        , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Time()        );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Status'      , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Status()      );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_M2'          , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_M2()          );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_M3'          , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_M3()          );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Barcode'     , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Barcode()     );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Price'       , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Price()       );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Discount'    , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Discount()    );
                $stmt->bindValue(':x_Number'      , $mStore_Order_DataClass->getx_Number()      );

                $stmt->execute();

                $mrowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
                echo "\nA :\n{$mrowCount}\n";

                return TRUE;
            } 
            catch (\PDOException $e)            
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

It seems there is no match and so there is no Update cause `$mrowCount` is 0

I see there is a match throgh ***DB browser for SQLITE***

[image: DB browser for SQLITE Log]

And also I put breakpoint in the code and below you can see the **$sql** from variable window of netbeans IDE:

> "UPDATE Orders SET x_Name = :x_Name, x_PhoneNumber1 = :x_PhoneNumber1,
>   x_PhoneNumber2 = :x_PhoneNumber2, x_Address1 = :x_Address1, x_Date =
>   :x_Date, x_Time = :x_Time, x_Status = :x_Status, x_M2 = :x_M2, x_M3 =
>   :x_M3, x_Barcode = :Barcode, x_Price = :x_Price, x_Discount =
>   :x_Discount, x_Number = :x_Number WHERE x_ID = :x_ID "

And:
[image]

So you can see there is a match for ID-2 while there no update occurs

*BTW,* *there is no error and TRUE is returned*

What's happening here?

Comment: Where are you showing what's in the database? You're just showing the value of `$mStore_Order_DataClass`.

Comment: The two screenshots are the same URL. Did you mean for one of them to show the table data?

Comment: Is a SELECT for the same :x_ID does not pull any results either, then the variable literal or database content do not match up (e.g. value with spaces).

Comment: sorry, I don't know why I can just upload 1 image while I repeated upload Just 1 image is uploaded,@ mario can you explain more (ID-2) is seen in the database browser and (ID-2) is seen in the debug of netbeans too

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed the code and finally found the problem as following:

> x_Barcode = :Barcode

It must be as following:

> x_Barcode = :**x_**Barcode

It was really a silent issue cause there was no error and the function returned true